# How to get the string that occures the most amount of times in a column (R)

Tags: r, string

I have this .txt file that has about 206k lines in it each containing the measurements of a certain building (numbered 1-193) and its power usage on a given date (each day for 1 year). I have two columns that store the buildings power usage on that given measurement ("norm_usage" and "usage"), "norm_usage" is stored as string (high, very high, very low, low, medium) and "usage" is stored as a number (193.32 , 323.36...). So what ive been trying to do is get the average power usage of each building for the last week.

Now ive had no problems with the column "usage" since the average is just the mean of the values, but when it comes to "norm_usage" i just cant get the value that appear most in my results (since i cant just mean() strings, i decided to use the value that has been measured most).

What ive done is, ive somehow managed to extract the past weeks measurements for the building im currently looking at and i get this

Nevermind the language these values basically mean high,low,very high etc.

So what im trying to do is to make another column in my original data set that would store the average norm_usage.

Now i know how to do that but i cant extract the most common string in my selection of data

My desired output would be something like this:

I get the selection of measurements i want:

```
print(podatki$norm_poraba[sel][sel2])
 [1] ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA VISOKA     ZELOVISOKA VISOKA     ZELOVISOKA VISOKA     ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA
[11] ZELOVISOKA VISOKA     ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA VISOKA     ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA
[21] ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA ZELOVISOKA
```

And then find the most common string that appears in these values:

```
mostcommon <- someCode
print(mostcommon)


>ZELOVISOKA
```

and then add it to the data i started with.

Comment: Welcome to SO; in the future, please notice that such questions are pure data handling ones, and they have nothing to do in themselves with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` (tags removed).

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't have to worry about ties (unclear whether you would or not based on your question), the following would work:

```r
s = sample(LETTERS, 250, rep = TRUE)
table(s)
#> s
#>  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z 
#>  6 10  5  6  8 13 10 11 14  7 10 14 13 11  6 13 11 10  7  9 11  9  9 10 12  5
names(sort(table(s), decreasing = TRUE))[1]
#> [1] "I"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Essentially you just need to use the `table` function to get the counts for each letter and sort those.

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you kind sir :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `table` if you don't care ties

```
sort(unique(s))[which.max(table(s)]
```